# how can i get the value of textview1 into textview2 after click the button?

Tags: android

i want the value of textview1 (which is asked by the user)is came into the textview2 after click the button.
can you help me in this?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you have some code ?

Comment: I think you mean putting the contents of an EditText into a TextView?
Look at the Methods of each Component. You have something like "getText()" and "setText(...)". Thats what you do when somebody clicks the Button.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextView1);
    TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextView2);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButton);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        textView2.setText(textView1.getText()); 
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
final TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.a);
        final TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.b);
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.c);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            textView2.setText(textView1.getText()); 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick(View view) {    
    if(view == clickBtn) {
         text2.setText(text1.getText().toString());
    }    
}
```